# How to add a CSS class to Django registration password form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm attempting to style (via classes) a Django password field.

I've successfully styled every other field other than the new password fields (password1 & 2).
[screen shot of current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo313.png)

My html:

```
<form method="post">
<ul>
        <li>{{ form.username }}</li>
        <li>{{ form.email }}</li>
        <li>{{ form.password1 }}</li>
        <li>{{ form.password2 }}</li>
        <li>{{ form.password }}</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

My forms.py:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta(UserCreationForm):
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'password')
    widgets = {
        'username': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'placeholder': "Username"
        }),
        'email': EmailInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'placeholder': 'Email address'
        }),
        'password1': PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'type': 'password',
            'name': 'password',
            'placeholder': 'Password'
        }),
        'password2': PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'placeholder': 'Password'
        }),
        'password': PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'placeholder': 'Password'
        }),
    }
```

Why are the new password and repeat password fields not displaying the style? I figured the name password1 was correct because I don't get any errors in forms.py as well as the HTML rending the input field.

How can I add classes to those two troublesome password fields?

Thank you very much for your time.

-Austin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why widget EmailInput style doesn't apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67764360/why-widget-emailinput-style-doesnt-apply)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It does not fully answer the question. I was able to format the email fields as your link explains, but it lacks an explanation for the password fields. Another member has answer my question below though. Thank you!

Comment: That does answer the part for the password fields too since it is the same issue for them (They are declared in `UserCreationForm` hence specifying `widgets` for them won't work). Although the link you found is a better duplicate target yes (The answer below won't work without it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the attrs , add "id" field  so that you can access the fields with their id and then you can apply css in that .

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta(UserCreationForm):
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'password')
    widgets = {
        'username': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'placeholder': "Username",
            'id' : "id_register_form_username" , 
        }),
        'email': EmailInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'placeholder': 'Email address' ,
            'id' : "id_register_form_email' , 
        }),
        'password1': PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'type': 'password',
            'name': 'password',
            'placeholder': 'Password',
            'id' : "id_register_form_password1" , 
        }),
        'password2': PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control text-lg h-8 rounded-full px-2 pt-1 border-2 border-black",
            'placeholder': 'Password'
            'id' : "id_register_form_password2" , 
        }),
    }
```

Then in your html , just use css using the id .

Comment: This worked! Thanks! 

I also found this late last night (after a few hours) that worked as well: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502854/css-not-working-on-django-password-form-field)

Comment: Awesome man . Great .